# How to make cloned select behave independantly of original?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, deep-copy

I have some logic written for a form where the available items in the second dropdown change based on the first selection.

The drop downs are cloned to allow the user to work with multiples if needed.

The cloned drop downs change if anything is changed in the original drop down.  The second field in the cloned options do not respond to change events in the first.

I would like for each cloned set of fields to behave independantly of the other sets of fields.  Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HchH8/

Why is this happening? I tried using clone(true, true) for deep copy and it didn't work. I have searched on SO for similar problems and I just can't wrap my head around the answers I'm finding. I am new to this. Can anyone help me please?

**jQuery**

```
    prods = {
    Cookware: ["- Select -", "Round French Oven", "Oval French Oven", "Braiser", "Skillet", "Fry Pan", "Grill Pan", "Saute Pan", "Saucepan", "Saucier", "Griddle", "Roaster", "Stockpot", "Speciality Cookware", "Other"],
    Bakeware: ["- Select -", "Covered Casserole", "Baking Dish", "Stoneware Gratin", "Speciality Bakeware", "Individual Bakeware", "Metal Bakeware", "Other"],
    KitchenTools: ["- Select -", "Utensils", "Kitchen Accessories", "Cutlery", "Wine Tools", "Textiles", "Other"],
    DineEntertain: ["- Select -", "Dinnerware", "Serveware", "Tabletop Accessories", "Glassware", "Kettles", "Tea Collection", "Café Collection", "Other"]
    };      
        var category = $('select[name^="Product_category"]');
        var productType = $('select[name^="Product_type"]');
        $('.prod-info').live("change", function () {
            var catSelected = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent("li").next("li.subCats").fadeIn('fast'); /*Fades in next option once selection has been made*/       
            if($(this).is(category)) {
                $('select[name^="Product_type"]').empty();  
                $('.product-size, .product-color').prop('selectedIndex',0);                 
                $.each(prods[catSelected], function (key, value) {
                    $('select[name^="Product_type"]')
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value)
                        .attr("name", value)
                        .text(value));
                });                     
            }
            if($(this).is(productType)) {
                $('.product-size, .product-color').prop('selectedIndex',0);                                     
            } 
        });         
        var otherSelect = $('select');
        var select = this.value;
        otherSelect.change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
                $(this).next('.other').show();
            }
            else $(this).next('.other').hide();
        });

        for (var i = 2; i < 6; i++) { // add counts in a for loop
            $('select[name="numProd"]').append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
        }


        $.fn.duplicate = function(count, cloneEvents) {
            var tmp = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                $.merge(tmp, this.clone(cloneEvents, true, true).get());
            }
            return this.pushStack(tmp);
        };

        //SELECT CHANGE FUNCTION (on change get value and clone)
        $('select[name="numProd"]').change(function(){  // on change...
            var numOfClones = $(this).val() -1;    // get value...
            var cntr = 2;
            $('#addProds').empty();              // empty holder if there are some old clones
            $('.prodDetails').duplicate(numOfClones).appendTo('#addProds').each(function() {
                $(this).find("select").each(function() {
                    if (this.name) {
                        this.name += cntr;
                    }
                    if (this.id) {
                        this.id += cntr;
                    }
                });
                ++cntr;
            });
        // duplicate; fill holder with new clones; the class 'new' is just for styling
        });
```

**HTML**

```
        <form id="warranty">
            <div id="prodDetailsContainer">
            <label for="numProd">How many products would you like to register (up to 5) <em>*</em></label> 
            <select name="numProd">
                    <option>1</option>
            </select>               
            <ul class="prodDetails" id="prod">
                <li>
                    <label for="Product_category">Product Category <em>*</em></label> 
                    <select name="Product_category" class="category prod-info" style="width: 160px;">
                        <option value="">- Select Category-</option>
                        <option value="Cookware">Cookware</option>
                        <option value="Bakeware">Bakeware</option>
                        <option value="KitchenTools">Kitchen Tools</option>
                        <option value="DineEntertain">Dine & Entertain</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li style="display: none;" class="subCats">
                    <label for="Product_type">Product Type <em>*</em></label> 
                    <select name="Product_type" class="product-type prod-info"></select>
                    <div class="other" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="Other_Product_Type">Specify Other:: </label> 
                        <input class="text-field" name="Other_Product_Type" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li style="display: none;" class="subCats">
                    <label for="Product_size">Product Size <em>*</em></label> 
                    <select name="Product_size" class="product-size prod-info" style="width: auto; outline: none; width:120px;">
                        <option value="">- Select Size -</option>
                        <option value="1_QT">1 qt.</option>
                        <option value="2_QT">2 qt.</option>
                        <option value="3-half_QT">3 &frac12; qt.</option>
                        <option value="4-half_QT">4 &frac12; qt.</option>
                        <option value="5_QT">5 qt.</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        <option value="NA">Not Applicable</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="other" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="Other_Product_Size">Specify Other:: </label> 
                        <input class="text-field" name="Other_Product_Size" />
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li style="display: none;" class="subCats">
                <label for="Product_color">Product Color <em>*</em></label> 
                    <select name="Product_color" class="product-color prod-info">
                        <option value="">- Select Color -</option>
                        <option value="Amethyst">Amethyst</option>
                        <option value="Aubergine">Aubergine</option>
                        <option value="Black Onyx">Black Onyx</option>
                        <option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="addProds"></div>               
            </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out- the solution was to move the variables inside the .on function, and also make the selectors more specific so that only the next fields were affected by a change in the previous (instead of all of them).

```
        $('select').live('change', function() {
            var category = $('select[name^="Product_category"]');
            var productType = $('select[name^="Product_type"]');
            var catSelected = $(this).val();
            var nextProdType = $(this).parent("li").next("li.subCats").children('select[name^="Product_type"]');
            var nextSizeColor = $(this).parent("li").next("li.subCats").children('.product-size, .product-color');                  
            $(this).parent("li").next("li.subCats").fadeIn('fast'); /*Fades in next option once selection has been made*/       
            if($(this).is(category)) {
                nextProdType.empty();   
                nextSizeColor.prop('selectedIndex',0);                  
                $.each(prods[catSelected], function (key, value) {
                    nextProdType
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value)
                        .attr("name", value)
                        .text(value));
                });                     
            }
            if($(this).is(productType)) {
                nextSizeColor.prop('selectedIndex',0);                                      
            } 
        });
```

Here is a working fiddle in case this will be helpful to others in the future:
http://jsfiddle.net/xJyL7/1/